# New gcc undefined symbol on pod

Tags: c++, compilation, c++17

I have a c++ code, compiled on centos7.9 and  running on kubernetes docker as a pod
The Dockerfile is based on "FROM centos:centos7.9.2009"

with compilation using gcc-5 it was working fine
after moving to gcc11 i get an error when running the executable

```
 symbol lookup error: /lib/libhutils.so: undefined symbol: _ZnamSt11align_val_t
```

when doing ldd on the lib that trow the error  i can see which libstd it is using

```
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ffff6cca000)
```

Here is the problematic function it is part of c++17

```
c++filt _ZnamSt11align_val_t
operator new[](unsigned long, std::align_val_t)
```

Comment: That `ldd` output does not say much. What _version_ of libstdc++ is installed in the container image and does it match the compiler version used?

Comment: yes it is the same version on both compilation and running pod 
 ll /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 19 Nov 13  2020 /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.19

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem was with the libtcmalloc not the same